# Powershell Script using Get-Wmi Object to get last password change date for local users on remote computers

Tags: powershell, wmi-query

I need a script to run against all of the machines in my domain to get Local account details. I want to use Get-WMIobject if possible because it works on remote machines without opening up extra security. I have used Get-WmiObject win32_User account to get many properties but it does not include password last changed time or groups the user account is a member off.
I can use net user command to get the information I need but only on a local computer and I can not get it to export to a csv. when I do this the only output I get is numbers. I am very new to scripting and powershell and any help would be greatly appreciated. I need this information to verify compliance requirements.

Comment: Please add some code to explain more, the community doesn

Comment: 't like to read just blocks of text. Srry about that, I accidentally pushed enter.

Comment: And my editing isn't working.

Comment: To put it somewhat differently, SO is here to solve (programming) problems not provide help. You can review the help resources for more info on what constitutes a good question.

Comment: Ok, I have seen many posts on here with people asking how to develop a powers hell script to do specific things. The only difference is they post the script that did not work and then someone posts a different script to solve the issue, can you recommend a site for someone who is new to scripting that doe provide HELP. It is difficult to find information on even the properties that are available with different commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
$computer='RemoteComputer'
$account='Administrator'
$objUser=[ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$account"|select @{l="PasswordAge";e={[string]$_.PasswordAge}}
$dtmChangeDate = (get-date).addseconds(-$objUser.PasswordAge)
'{0}\{1} password last changed {2:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}' -f $computer,$account,$dtmChangeDate|write-host
```